# can javascript sort strings containing numbers?

Tags: javascript, sorting

I'm making a little web-app in which I used AHK and javascript.
I make AHK a group of images paths to the .js file something like this

```
var importedFiles = [
 "file:///F:/image1.jpg",
 "file:///F:/image10.jpg",
 "file:///F:/image11.jpg",
 "file:///F:/image2.jpg",
]
```

and these images should be viewed in the browser the problem is that the sorting method of the two languages is not like the windows sorting.

What I want is javascript sort the file in the variable so that they are like they are viewed in windows like this

```
var importedFiles = [
 "file:///F:/image1.jpg",
 "file:///F:/image2.jpg",
 "file:///F:/image10.jpg",
 "file:///F:/image11.jpg",
]
```

BTW : I've searched for the functions posted before but it only works with number only and strings containing number like this case

Comment: another question guys, can I find if a string consist of only number , spaces and dashes(-) or there are some characters in the name? 
can I do that?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
var importedFiles = [
 "file:///F:/image1.jpg",
 "file:///F:/image10.jpg",
 "file:///F:/image11.jpg",
 "file:///F:/image2.jpg",
]

var customSort = function (a, b) {
    return (Number(a.match(/(\d+)/g)[0]) - Number((b.match(/(\d+)/g)[0])));

}

// use sort() and apply the customSort function
console.log(importedFiles.sort(customSort));

//outputs

[
   "file:///F:/image1.jpg", 
   "file:///F:/image2.jpg", 
   "file:///F:/image10.jpg", 
   "file:///F:/image11.jpg"
]
```

**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/warihi/1/edit)**

Comment: Thanks a lot i use you method but add another function to get what I want

Comment: What if we have a string without the number?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regex to get the number in the filename (assuming your filenames have a pattern to it like the example you have given at the top) and sort it according to it.

```
var r = /[A-Za-z\:\/]+([0-9]+)\.jpg/;
importedFiles.sort(function(f1, f2) {
     var match1 = r.exec(f1);
     var num1 = match1[1];

     var match2 = r.exec(f2);
     var num2 = match2[1];

     //now you have the two numbers in num1 and num2
     return parseInt(num1, 10) - parseInt(num2, 10);
});
```

importedFiles will now contain the sorted array as you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to split the string to sort it, using a `for` loop and the `.split()` method.

Example JS:

```
function sortNumber(a,b) {
    return a - b;
}
var arrayToSort = ["Orange1","Orange3","Orange2"];
Numbers=[];
sortedArray = [];
for(var i = 0; i< arrayToSort.length; i++) {
    numberValue = arrayToSort[i].split("Orange")[1]//Returns number in string
    Numbers.push(numberValue).sort(sortNumber)
    //Numbers now contains a sorted list of the numbers
}
for(var i = 0; i < arrayToSort.length; i++) {
    for(var j = 0; j < arrayToSort.length; j++) {
        if(arrayToSort[j].indexOf(Numbers[i]) !== -1) {
            sortedArray.push(arrayToSort[j])
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: your case solving only same set of words before numbers