# sort() JS function doesn't give the expected result

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I'm trying to sort this array.

```
array = new Array();
array[0] = "Population23"
array[1] = "Population3"
```

So i used the sort function like this `array.sort()`
And it gives me :

```
array[0] = "Population23"
array[1] = "Population3"
```

Instead of :

```
array[0] = "Population3"
array[1] = "Population23"
```

Why ? And how can i fix this to give me the "Instead of" result ?

Comment: Which type of sort do you need? sort goes alphabetically, so it makes sense what it gives in output

Comment: What are you basing your expected result on? The length of the string?

Comment: Nice find, @Nina!

Comment: No, just the Population3 is less than Population23, because of the 3 and 23. So how can i change this ?

Comment: The default sort is *lexicographic*: it compares the strings character by character, (more accurately: code unit by code unit) and stops when it finds a difference. Since `"2"` is less than `"3"`, it stops when it reaches that point of the strings, saying that `"Population23"` is less than `"Population3"` (because in string terms, it is). If you want to compare them lexicographically except for the numbers at the end, you'll have to write a custom comparison function.

Comment: When comparing large numbers of strings, such as in sorting large arrays, it is better to create an Intl.Collator object and use the function provided by its compare property.
`const collator = new Intl.Collator(undefined, {numeric: true, sensitivity: 'base'}); const array = ['Population23', 'Population3']; console.log(array.sort(collator.compare));`

by passing `numerice:true` option it browsers recognize numbers and you can do case-sensivity:'base' for it aswell

Comment: refer to link
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29180284/can-javascript-sort-strings-containing-numbers